# How to force a while loop to restart code?

Tags: python, http, while-loop

When running the below code, if an error occurs or a connection times out, it triggers the loop so that the 'retrying code' is printed. But the code doesn't restart. It continuously prints 'retrying code' but that is all.

I wonder if it is anything to with the fact that the 'testingfile123.py' is working with http.requests?

```
import time 
import os 
os.system('python testingfile123.py')


while True:
    try:
        testingfile123.py()
        print('running code')
    except:
        time.sleep(5)
        print('retrying code')
```

Comment: ... What is the statement `testingfile123.py()` supposed to be? That will always cause an exception because it does not make sense. The code that executes your `testing123` file is `os.system('python testingfile123.py')` which is outside your loop.

Comment: If it prints `'retrying code'` continuously, it means that `testingfile123.py()` always fails with the exception

Answer (score 0):

Isn't this caused by the while True loop? Even if the code goes to the except section, it will just wait 5 seconds and print "retrying code". You would need some break statement.

Comment: But in going to the except section, even if a break is added - would that then trigger the 'try' part again?

Comment: @HWJ5 The try part is triggered again, but all that does is throw an exception again, because the code in your try part does not make sense.

Comment: @khelwood I'm confused as to why you say it doesn't make sense? As when I first run the code, it works how it should - it is only thrown off when a timeout / error occurs..

Comment: `testingfile123.py()` will *always* throw an exception because the name `testingfile123` is not bound to any value in your program. When you run the code and don't see a problem yet it's because your execution hasn't got to that line yet.

Comment: I agree with what Khelwood said. You should change your code so that it can land on the "try" part, or make a new way out from the "exception" part.

Comment: @khelwood okay thanks. How would I fix this?

Comment: If you want `os.system('python testingfile123.py')` to be executed repeatedly, that bit needs to be inside the loop. Get rid of `testingfile123.py()`, it's meaningless. And when you get an exception, at least print it out so you know what error you are catching.